# Understanding XQuery position(): inclusive or exclusive end position

Tags: xquery

I have read a lot of XQuery position, but all examples are about `>`, `<`, or `=`. But you can also use `x - y` and I am confused as to what is inclusive and what is not.

```
[position() = $startPosition to $endPosition]
```

Let's say $startPosition is `1` (as I have read that position does not start with 0 but with 1), what will return the first hit? $endPosition set to `1` as well, or to `2`?

In other words, given an expected return of `n`, what would be the formula for both variables? To make things more clear, we can add an incrementing loop (`$iteration`). Basically we are generating a search that will find all subsequent hits with position. (As an example.)

```
$endPosition = 1 + ($iteration * n);
$startPosition = $endPosition - n;
```

This is what I came up with. This will result in the following outcome, for `$iteration` starting from 1 and incrementing, and `n` of 3.

```
1: 
$endPosition = 1 + (1 * 3);   // 4
$startPosition = 4 - 3;       // 1
2: 
$endPosition = 1 + (2 * 3);   // 7
$startPosition = 7 - 3;       // 4
3: 
$endPosition = 1 + (3 * 3);   // 10
$startPosition = 10 - 3;      // 7
```

But, is this correct? I am not sure. Is the `$endPosition` included? If not, my code is correct, if not - it isn't, and then I am interested in the correct formula.

Comment: I don't get what you're after at all. You're talking about subsequences, then you do some arithmetics which do not really seem related. Could you add an example that explains your intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `$sequence[position() = $a to $b]` is equivalent to the following *FLWOR* expression (where `$position` start at `1`):

```
for $x at $position in $seq
where $position >= $a and $position <= $b
return $x
```

So to skip the first two items and then return the following five, you need `$seq[position() = 3 to 7]`.

Here is how you can go from this to a subsequence function that uses a  `0`-based *offset* and the number of items to return:

```
declare function local:subsequence(
  $seq as item()*,
  $offset as xs:integer,
  $length as xs:integer
) as item()* {
  let $start := $offset + 1,
      $end   := $offset + $length
  return $seq[position() = $start to $end]
};

local:subsequence(1 to 100, 0, 5), (: returns (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) :)
local:subsequence(1 to 100, 13, 3) (: returns (14, 15, 16) :)
```

Comment: So, by that example, both $a (start) and $b (end) are *inclusive*, right? 1-2 goes through one and two, subsequent is then 3-4, then 5-6, and so on - rather than 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 - if you want each code to return a different position without overlap.

Comment: Correct. The `=` operator in XQuery is has *existential semantics* when its inputs are non-singleton sequences; `$value1 = $value2` is equivalent to `some $a in $value1, $b in $value2 satisfies $a eq $b` where `eq` is equality on single `item()`s. This also means that `$seq[position() = $a to $b]` is equivalent to `for $pos in $a to $b return $seq[$pos]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear the specific problem you're trying to solve, so I don't know if this answers your question, but let's unpack that expression first:

```
[position() = $startPosition to $endPosition]
```

Say `$startPosition` is 1 and `$endPosition` is 3. That will evaluate to:

```
[position() = (1, 2, 3)]
```

That predicate will return true any time `position()` equals any of the values in the sequence on the right.